# Figured out models but issues with object not being found and dredge command

Tags: r, mixed-model

After some amazing help, especially from @jbowman, I was ready to get into my models but have hit a snag that I don't understand.
I decided to try package MuMIn as it works with lme4 so that I am able to do all the models in once shot rather than running them each one at a time. However apart from loading it and then loading lme4 I have not had a chance to use it as I am getting an error and not sure why. Could someone please look at the code and see what I am doing wrong? My original post is here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24971/mixed-effects-model-equations

It is basically telling me that it cannot find "Feeding" but when I type in the name of the df it lists all columns. So I tried to enter it as a `factor` (not `as.factor`) as you can see with no effect. I would like to attach my .csv file but I don't see an option to do this. :(

Here is what I am getting

```
> local({pkg <- select.list(sort(.packages(all.available = TRUE)),graphics=TRUE)
+ if(nchar(pkg)) library(pkg, character.only=TRUE)})
Warning message:
package ‘MuMIn’ was built under R version 2.14.1 
> local({pkg <- select.list(sort(.packages(all.available = TRUE)),graphics=TRUE)
+ if(nchar(pkg)) library(pkg, character.only=TRUE)})
Loading required package: Matrix
Loading required package: lattice

Attaching package: ‘Matrix’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:base’:

    det


Attaching package: ‘lme4’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    AIC, BIC

> ABMtest.df<-read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)
> ABMtest.df$Brood<-as.factor(ABMtest.df$Brood)
> ABMtest.df$Site<-as.factor(ABMtest.df$Site)
> ABMtest.df$Age.class<-as.factor(ABMtest.df$Age.class)
> ABMtest.df$MF.vs.OF<-as.factor(ABMtest.df$MF.vs.OF)
> ABMtest.df$tide.h.l<-as.factor(ABMtest.df$tide.h.l)
> fm2test<-lmer(Feeding~MF.vs.OF+Age.class+tide.h.l+Site+HDp+(1|Brood))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Feeding' not found
> ABMtest.df$Feeding<-factor(ABMtest.df$Feeding)
> fm2test<-lmer(Feeding~MF.vs.OF+Age.class+tide.h.l+Site+HDp+(1|Brood))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Feeding' not found
>
```

Last time after I listed everything I finally got it to run (but not sure how because i cannot replicate this. But last time I then typed the code:

```
ms2test<-dredge(fm2test, trace=TRUE, rank="AICc", REML=FALSE)
```

Which is supposed to give me the ranks of all the models using AICc and allows me to list the models etc. but it says something like not being able to find class "mer" with fixef. I have no idea.

If someone could see why Feeding is not recognised, or is this because I didn't list first? And then anyone who is familiar with the dredge command help with that then it would greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just got it to work as I added ,`data=ABMtest.df` after `(1|brood)`. Could adding the Feeding as a factor (not as.factor) have cause harm though?
However I am still having an issue:
`> fm2test<-lmer(Feeding~MF.vs.OF+Age.class+tide.h.l+Site+HDp+(1|Brood), data=ABMtest.df)`

`> ms2test<-dredge(fm2test, trace=TRUE, rank="AICc", REML=FALSE)`

`1 : lmer(formula = Feeding ~ (1 | Brood), data = ABMtest.df)
Error in UseMethod("fixef") : 
  no applicable method for 'fixef' applied to an object of class "mer"`

Comment: Technically I could run all the models by hand, but as I have about 10 factors for each it would take forever. :(

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the data= argument.  You have to tell lmer which data frame to look at.

```
fm2test<-lmer(Feeding~MF.vs.OF+Age.class+tide.h.l+Site+HDp+(1|Brood), data=ABMtest.df)
```

Comment: As in my comments, I had fixed that but then I got the mer error. I then re ran the whole thing again and just named the data frame ABMtest rather than ABMtest.df and everything ran fine. Is that an issue? All the examples just use a name not `.df`

Comment: shouldn't make any difference having .df as part of the name.

Comment: Then I think I have it. Thank you. Does anyone know which script is the best just to run all models with dredge and then show them in order with AICc values?

Comment: There are two options:
`fm1 <- lm(y ~ ., data = Cement)`

`ms1 <- dredge(fm1)`

`plot(ms1)`

`model.avg(ms1, subset = delta < 4)`

`confset.95p <- get.models(ms1, cumsum(weight) <= .95)`

`avgmod.95p <- model.avg(confset.95p)`

`summary(avgmod.95p)`

`confint(avgmod.95p)`

But would this work with lmer?

OR

Comment: #Model-averaging mixed models

library(nlme)
data(Orthodont, package = "nlme")
# Fit model by REML
`fm2 <- lme(distance ~ Sex*age, data = Orthodont,
random = ~ 1 | Subject, method = "REML")`
# Model selection: ranking by AICc using ML
`ms2 <- dredge(fm2, trace = TRUE, rank = "AICc", REML = FALSE)`
`(attr(ms2, "rank.call"))`
# Get the models (fitted by REML, as in the global model)
`fmList <- get.models(ms2, 1:4)`
# Because the models originate from ’dredge(..., rank = AICc, REML = FALSE)’,
# the default weights in ’model.avg’ are ML based:
`summary(model.avg(fmList))`

Comment: You can also use the program to list AICc too for each model, but you have to input the models.

Comment: I used the second model and then ran each by hand and got the same results so I will use that:
If I could just ask one more question. I ran a model
`lmer(y~A+B+(1|C), data=dataset, REML=FALSE)`

I then had it run all four iterations. Three out of four had a delta value below 2. The 0 was the `y~(1|C)` with a weight of 0.5 the the other two were `y~A+(1|Brood)` and 'y~B+(1|Brood)` with weights of 0.3 and 0.2. A and B are also categorical data, in this case 'site' and 'age.class'. Would it therefore be good to add these as random effects too for analysis of the other factors...

Comment: ...such as habitat type and tide levels and such. The reason why I ask that is that another study had 'site' as a random effect after doing such a test (hence why I did it) and they ran adults and chicks separately because of age.class differences. However they had more factors in their initial test and I worry that the only reason they are weighted is because there a few options. Should I run an anova with `y~A+(1|Brood)` with `y~(1|Brood). Would this give me a true p-vale of whether 'site' or 'age.class' has a real effect? Or shall I just run a complete model and see what happens?

Comment: ...just a note 3 broods are nested in one site and four in the other site